# Help Testing ATX PSU 8 Pin PCIE Connector

Tags: power-supply, voltage-measurement, troubleshooting

I'm trying to do some pin swapping on an 8 pin PCIE power cable. It didn't come with my PSU, so I know it's probably not going to work how it is. I've done research on how to test and swap the pins and I think I understand the process.

My question is: Why is the highest voltage reading I can read anywhere on the connector around 2.7V? I see the pinout for the connector says 12V, and all 3 of the bottom "12V" pins are reading 2.7

Could someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Anything helps! Thank you!

Comment: There is not much to work with. Is the cable detachable so it has connectors on both ends? With what you are measuring and how? Is the supply turned on? Is there a load connected? Is the meter set to measure DC?

Comment: It is a 2 sided connector (2 male). I was using a  basic multimeter I got from fleet farm. I was measuring DC volts as well. The supply is on and the fans are running. There isn't a load connected though, is that required? If so, how would I go about adding a load that isn't the graphics card? Thank you!

Comment: Either the meter is broken or you are measuring incorrectly. Has the meter ever worked? You don't say what you connect where and how to make a measurement. Also many computer supplies fail to provide stable output without load. How did you manage to turn on the supply if you have nothing connected? You can add load to the other wires.

Comment: This is my 1st time using it, I suppose I could test it on a cut USB wire to make sure it reads 5v to verify it works. I used a paperclip to jump 2 of the pins on 24pin. If the clip part is on the bottom and the pins are facing you, it's the bottom 4th and 5th from the right. I was just poking around at all the combinations of pins. I'm assuming if it was reading +2.7v then the black is on a GND and red is connected to a power pin? How would I go about adding a load? If the pins output voltage, is it safe to assume they are the +12v lines? Also, 1 of the pins does nothing. (Sense pin?)